# Are wet mergers good for star formation?

Tags: astrophysics, galaxies

In my astrophysics lecture my professor said wet mergers are bad for star formation since it often results in gas being fed to the black hole. In the wiki however it says the opposite. [image]

What is the right answer?

Comment: found this talk https://www.naoj.org/Science/SubaruUM/SubaruUM2007/jan29/session4/llin.ppt

Answer (score 1):

Wet mergers trigger strong star formation.

It is *also* true that it feeds gas to the central supermassive Black Holes, but the gas fraction lost to the BH is very modest, there'll be plenty left for star formation.

What basically happens is that the gas in the two systems is slammed together, triggering overdensities and subsequent gravitational collapse.

The galaxies with the highest known star formation rates have a very large fraction of merger or strongly interacting systems; they have disturbed "train wreck" morphology (see e.g. the [Lyman Alpha Reference Sample](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014ApJ...782....6H/abstract) (disclaimer: I am a co-author of the linked paper).